# Using AngularFire2 Auth live: Error cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '__/auth/iframe'

Tags: angular, firebase, angular2-routing, angular-cli, angularfire2

I have a simple site in Angular 2 with Firebase Google Auth:

**app.routes.ts**

```
...
export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
...
loginWithGoogle(): firebase.Promise<any> {
    return this.af.auth.login({
        provider: AuthProviders.Google,
        method: AuthMethods.Popup
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error("Google Auth: ", error);
    });
}
```

**login.component.ts**

```
...
login() {
    this.authService.loginWithGoogle().then((data) => {
        this.router.navigate(['']);
    }).catch((error) => {
        this.error = error;
    });
}
```

On my localhost, everything works great. But as soon as I've deployed to firebaseapp hosting, (or even run localhost live-server from the ng built dist folder), I get greeted with this error on a login:

*EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): 
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '__/auth/iframe'*

***zone_symbol__error: 
Error: Cannot match any routes. 
URL Segment: '**/auth/iframe' at y (https://...*

Comment: Do you have a service worker in your app that rewrites all URLs to an index.html? If so, you'll need to exclude `/__/*` from that rewrite, as it's a reserved space for Firebase that is used by e.g. Firebase Auth.

Comment: Yes. In fact PWA methods were the reason for this little project. I didn't make the connection. Thank you, I'll check it out.

Comment: Funny thing. I tested it incognito and it worked without errors. So I just unregistered my service workers and all was well with the next reload. Not sure now what the original problem was. Can't recreate.
P.S. service-workers were automatically generated with sw-precache.

Comment: Have you figured this out? I have the same problem after generation service worker with `sw-precache`

Comment: No. I need to try again. Moved onto another project without Firebase.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh how do you exclude `/__/*`. My current `sw-precache-config.js` looks like this: https://pastebin.com/d7mZRe7n

Comment: @Ciprian I'm still testing, but try adding
`navigateFallback: '/index.html',
navigateFallbackWhitelist: [/^(?!\/__)/],`
to your sw-precache-config.js

Comment: thanks. I ended up redoing the whole service worker setup and it worked. Try this: https://coryrylan.com/blog/fast-offline-angular-apps-with-service-workers